# Add another function to sort string

Tags: python, string, sorting

This is my code:

```
# Read in the file
    with open('users.csv', 'r') as file :
      filedata = file.read()
    
    # Replace the target string
    filedata = filedata.replace(',', '\n')
    
    
    # Write the file out again
    with open('file2.csv', 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
```

The output file looks something like this:

```
abba
zada
luta
```

I wanna make it so the file is sorted alphabetically.. How do I add this function aswell?

Original csv file looks like this abba,zada,luta..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just added answer to me problem. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Solution to my question.

```
var1 = open("/path/to/file/file.csv",'r').read().strip().split(',')

var2 = open("/path/to/file/newFile.csv", "w")

for i in sorted(var2):
    var2.write(str(i + "\n"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).